# In vue3 apexChart I added a dataLabels but when zooming in the labels are showing wrong

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, zooming, apexcharts

I am using the vue3 apexChart for an advanced time line chart.
I wrote a formatter in dataLabels as below:

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: (y, {seriesIndex, dataPointIndx,w}) => {
        var isNight= this.isAtNight(y[0],y[1]); // this returns if it has an hour between 22 to 05
        var nightIcon= '\U263D';
        var dayIcon= '\U2600';
        var icon= isNight ? nightIcon: dayIcon;
        var zValue= this.series[seriesIndex].data[dataPointIndx].z;
        return icon + ' ' + zValue;
    },
}
```

In my apexChart tag in the HTML i added

```
@dataPointSelection: = "dataPointSelection"
```

When I zoom in I still see all labels even those that are out of the zoomed part.

I would like your help thanks in advance

I want the labels to show only if the object is showing on the chart.
Now I see all labels even if the object is not showing.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, edit your post and add code with `code tag`. No need of thanks in advance. We are here to help, anyway.